# how to make that "$nearSphere" return also the items without any coordinates?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I try to do a `$nearSphere` query like below :

```
"coordinates":{
  "$nearSphere":{
    "$geometry":{
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[7.16,47.13]}}},
```

The problem is that it doesn't return me the documents that doesn't have a node "`coordinates`" (even at the end of the list). Is their a way to force `$nearSphere` to return documents (at the end of the list) that don't have a node "`coordinates`" node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in a single query.

$nearSphere requires a geospatial index. Documents without coordinates are excluded from the index and basically are not visible to the query.

You can make the second query to find all documents without coordinates tho:

```
.find({"coordinates": {$exists: false}})
```

and union both cursors on application level.

Alternatively you can run both queries in a single pipeline with $facet to combine the results on the db side.